# Re-order Apple TV Home Screen icons?

Tags: jailbreak, appletv

I'm currently running the old version of Apple TV (4.4.4) but I've been considering upgrading, now that the new version has an untethered jailbreak. I use the Apple TV primarily for FireCore's Media Player (files off my NAS) and Netflix.

Now that the new UI just throws a ton of icons out there, is there any way to order them? Or by chance, do they re-order themselves based on usage?

I don't ever use iTunes Movies, TV Shows, or Music, so I'd really hate for the entire first row to always be useless to me. With the current version I can at least use Overflow to hide the menus I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This forum post details what I think is a better way of hiding unwanted ATV apps:

http://forum.firecore.com/topic/7696

I've used it to successfully hide the icons for MLB, NHL, and NBA. I also hid MobileMe photos (com.apple.frontrow.appliance.internet.dot-mac) -- seeing as MobileMe is being retired this month. I suspect Apple will issue an ATV update to remove that menu item too at the end of June. But it's good to know us jailbreakers can handle this ourselves!

I am not sure what com.apple.frontrow.appliance.internet.internet-photos links to?

I note there is also com.apple.frontrow.appliance.internet.photo-stream (for Photo Stream) and com.apple.frontrow.appliance.internet.flickr (for Flickr.)

Next up, I'd love to discover a way to re-order these icons...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that you can reorder them, and they don't reorder themselves, but you can remove unwanted channels, according to this blog entry:
http://imho.nu/iMHo/media-player-position/.
Essentially, you SSH in and rename the file of channels you don't use. The website gives some more detail, so I would check it out.

Comment: Thanks! Does this work for the other apps too, like MLB, Vimeo, and the other 'bottom' channels? I want to get rid of all of them...

Comment: I imagine so, but unfortunately I don't have a Apple TV to test it with. I'm just going off what that website said.

Comment: Now, on the current 5.2 software, it's a lot easier to hide any apps you don't want, simply by using Parental Controls.  Works on all of them... NHL, MLB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6 Beta Allows Reordering of Icons on Apple TV

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4XlSrc4Xuk

http://www.macrumors.com/2012/06/27/ios-6-beta-allows-reordering-of-icons-on-apple-tv/